# ElGamal recovering messages

Tags: elgamal-encryption

If you use the same ephemeral key in Elgamal, someone can read the future messages. I have two ciphertexts $y_1=62$ and $y_2=4$. The difference between two plaintexts is $x_1-x_2=138$

how do I get $x_1$ and $x_2$? Modulo is $157$

Comment: Hint: Try and write down what y1-y2 actually means and what you can do with it.

Comment: I have no idea.. sitting with this problem for an hour

Comment: @Moar321, it looks like you have accidently created two accounts, you may want to have a look at [this help center page](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: hint: $y_1=x_1\cdot h$, where $h$ is some unknown value. Now imagine what happens when you calculate $y_1-y_2$. Hint: writing down the resulting equality usually helps

Comment: So I calculated 58=138*x mod 157, now shall I find x with brute force or is there other way? I know x is 30 but are there easier ways to calculate it? So my KM is 30, and KM=y1*x^-1 mod p so 30=62*x1^-1 mod 157 => x^-1 is 41 also x1 is 23. But can I figure it out in better way, assuming I use higher numbers so brute force wouldnt take me ages during test?

Comment: Another hint: try and write down $y_1-y_2=???$ and try to fill in the right side as per the definition of $y_1,y_2$. Now try to apply some basic math and see what values you know and which you don't know. Recover the unknown from that equation and recover the plaintexts with the definitions afterwards.

Comment: Did you already had the [EEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) in class? It should do the trick.

Comment: Okay I inversed the KM and got x1=y1*KMi mod p, 62*89 mod 157=23 and x2=4*89 mod 157=41 Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Because the current answers may be a bit cryptic, I'll make a quick write-up of the solution of this one, as the asker has already figured out the solution and the way himself.

---

First thing to notice: $y_1=x_1\cdot h$ and $y_2=x_2\cdot h$, where $h$ is $g^{ak}$ where $a$ is the recipient's private key and $k$ is the ephemeral key of the message, it's assumed static for this. Let $p$ be the known modulus.

First note that $y_1-y_2=x_1\cdot h-x_2\cdot h=(x_1-x_2)\cdot h\pmod p$ and thus $(y_1-y_2)\cdot(x_1-x_2)^{-1}=h\pmod p$, where $x_1-x_2$ is known. Using this one can recover $x_1=y_1\cdot h^{-1}\pmod p$ and $x_2=y_2\cdot h^{-1}\pmod p$ using the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).